# Difficulty with slow-running vba script in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I'm looking for help in making this excerpt of code run more quickly. I've tried a few tricks like saving the values in arrays and then evaluating them and turning off Screen Updating & Calculation while the code runs but it still takes an extraordinary amount of time.

I recognize there are a Ton of records to run through but I'm hoping some more veteran programmers could offer me some sage advice.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim w As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim srch() As Variant
Dim ent() As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C134743")
ReDim srch(1 To 134742)
Set rng1 = Sheets("ExampleSheet").Range("F2:F63078")
ReDim ent(1 To 63077)

For x = 1 To 134742
    srch(x) = rng.Cells(x, 1).Value
Next x

For w = 1 To 63077
    ent(w) = rng1.Cells(w, 1).Value
Next w

For z = 1 To 134742

    For y = 1 To 63077

        If CStr(srch(z)) = ent(y) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("AA2:AA134743").Cells(z, 1) = "Example_True"
            GoTo jmp
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("AA2:AA134743").Cells(z, 1) = "Example_False"
        End If

    Next y

jmp:

Next z

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Find command to find the cell matching your desired data.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon is correct. If you still need to use the arrays, you can load them directly from the range. `ent = rng1` (just be mindful that is n,1 array).

Comment: This should be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - I've flagged it so hopefully it will get moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be faster:

```
Sub TT()

    Dim z As Long, y As Long
    Dim srch As Variant, ent As Variant, v
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng As Range, c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C134743")
    srch = rng.Value

    Set rng1 = Sheets("ExampleSheet").Range("F2:F63078")
    ent = rng1.Value

    For z = 1 To UBound(srch, 1)
        Set c = rng.Cells(z).EntireRow.Cells(1, "AA")
        v = CStr(srch(z, 1))
        For y = 1 To UBound(ent, 1)
            If v = ent(y, 1) Then
                c.Value = "Example_True"
                GoTo jmp
            End If
        Next y
        c.Value = "Example_False" 'only do this once!
jmp:

    Next z

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off automatic calculations

you also dont need activesheet so much. with:

```
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C134743")
```

you could just tell it what sheet it is i.e. sheetx.range etc.

Also you seem to pass a bunch of variables around needlessly. It look slike you could retool this to do it in a simpler way. COuldnt you just use index/match to filter out true/false?